# Avoid sending images to irrelevents in website

Tags: web

I made a website that will auto-generate some graphs depending on different accounts.

First I try to generate an image (png) with the according file name, then send the png to a server and then delete the png when the server received any other get or post requests.

However, when considering the case where there is an access of person B just after the graph is auto generated that was meant originally for person A. The graph may be deleted due to the same file name and becomes the graph for person B, which is then send to both (in my understanding).

So, I try to generate different file names for the pngs generated for different accounts. However, other accounts although may not see the png on website, but they may still be able to get others' png through path. Is it possible to avoid sending the images to irrelevent recipients in a website using this mechanism of auto-generating pngs?

Sorry for my poor English. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should improve your tags: the description of the "web" tag says "do not use this tag", so please try to be more specific (what language do you use?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the option is keep name of the files as complex as possible like 32 character's random string (more the length more is the security) e.g.

> we234fgt4lpx123cuyiedsd12cds345sd.png

It will be difficult for others to guess names of the files since combination will be difficult to guess.

**Option 2:**

If in case you have login based access then you can make use of database table where two columns will be used 1. **File Name**  & 2. **SessionId**.

So every time you can validate whether session ID of the logged user with the column value of "Session ID column" If both matches then only provide access to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!